# Different Google Cloud Function Call For Different Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, region

I'm currently working on a project where there are two different storage buckets (one in US central and another in S. Korea).

It would be more efficient both cost-wise and speed-wise to locate the functions for updating storage usage in same location as storage.

But, now I want to manage the function at two different location. This function is meant to update the Firestore whenever new image is uploaded in a storage.

This is the code that I thought would work (but actually don't)

```
exports.incrementUsedSize = functions.region('us-central1').storage.object().onFinalize
exports.incrementUsedSizeKr = functions.region('asia-northeast3').storage.object().onFinalize
```

But both of these are called whenever storage at US or S. Korea is updated.

Is there a way to make these functions work at two locations without interfering each other?

I mean, is there a way to restrict the scope of the function to the storage at specific location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation:

> To set the region where a function runs, set the region parameter in the function
> definition as shown:

```
exports.incrementUsedSize = functions
    .region('us-central1')
    .storage
    .object()
    .onFinalize((object) => {
      // ...
    });
```

The `.region()` sets the location for your cloud function and has nothing to do with the bucket.

However, as you say the buckets are different and not a single "dual-region" bucket, you should be able to deploy this way:

```
gcloud functions deploy incrementUsedSize \
--runtime nodejs10 \
--trigger-resource YOUR_TRIGGER_BUCKET_NAME \
--trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

by specifying the trigger bucket you should be able to restrict the invocation trigger. More details in the [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#deploying_the_function)

If your question refers to *Firebase* Cloud Function then you can specify the bucket name as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events#trigger-function-on-storage-changes):

```
exports.incrementUsedSize = functions.storage.bucket('bucketName').object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  // ...
});
```